# Why my rsync -Hav is not copying hard links?

Tags: rsync, hard-link

I know this has been asked before, but for some reason my version of `rsync -H` does not seem to be working consistently.

I have a backup system with lots of hard links. I want to copy the thing to a bigger disk. So I did this:

`rsync -Hav /source/fotoshp /source/fotoshp-M-2 /dest`

Yet, in `source` I have this, with the same inode:

```
# ls -li fotoshp-M-2/0902_aves_se/index.html fotoshp/0902_aves_se/index.html
9290102 -rw-r--r-- 14 gato gato 12042 Dec  4  2016 fotoshp/0902_aves_se/index.html
9290102 -rw-r--r-- 14 gato gato 12042 Dec  4  2016 fotoshp-M-2/0902_aves_se/index.html
```

while in `dest` I have this:

```
# ls -li fotoshp-M-2/0902_aves_se/index.html fotoshp/0902_aves_se/index.html
78908017 -rw-r--r-- 1 gato gato 12042 Dec  4  2016 fotoshp/0902_aves_se/index.html
79435377 -rw-r--r-- 1 gato gato 12042 Dec  4  2016 fotoshp-M-2/0902_aves_se/index.html
```

So, the file has been copied to another inode, destroying the hard link. The strange thing is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't...

The `rsync` version I use is `rsync-3.1.2-5.fc26.x86_64`.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with the same version of `rsync` on OpenBSD 6.1.

Comment: Are all links in the source directory?  If 13 of the 14 links above are outside the source directory there's no point in copying them.

Comment: In fact, I waited for the `rsync` command to finish, and for some reason at the end the hard links were preserved. However, during the sync process, rsync copied the files themselves.

Comment: @SatōKatsura All links in the source dir. This is a periodic backup drive.

Comment: What filesystem on the destination?

Comment: ext4 fs on  both.